# How to render a GridView as an accordion menu with JQuery

Tags: javascript, css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to render a simple gridView as a jQuery accordion menu.  [In this link](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Accordion_Data_Binding_GridView_Example.aspx) I found exactly what I need, but it's all made in `asp.net`.  I need to find some idea in jQuery.

Has anybody any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) is a great solution for editable tables, and it's in jQuery as per your requirement. [Here's the link to a bunch of examples that Slickgrid references](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples)